# how to configure cron as jenkins string parameter for AWS Lamda

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-lambda, cron, jenkins-pipeline

I have an [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) function which is running once everyday through a cron defined in my  [CloudFormation.yaml](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html). The current cron is written as below.

```
Events:
StartScheduledEvent:
    Type: Schedule
    Properties:
       Schedule: cron (0 8? * MON-FRI *)
```

Is there any way to move the cron to jenkins string parameter so that code changes wont be required while changing cron duration.

I can change the cron through console but my organization does allow not changing anything through Console but only CI/CD.

Comment: use environment variables?

Comment: tried it. 
Jenkin is not allowing * in property 
Even if add the property with in ""